# Are there any Java libraries which I can use for automated testing of Windows GUIs?

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, automated-tests, fitnesse

Currently I am doing automated integration testing using FitNesse (Java) and have successfully plugged-in Watij to access a web-based application. I would like to extend this to also drive Windows GUI (non-Java) applications. To this end, are there any Java libraries available which I can use in a similar way?

Answer (score 1):

Matt,

I don't think you are going to be able to test your non-java GUIs with Java libraries.

That being said, you could take a look at AutomationAnywhere (.com) and see if that fits your needs.  This tool is very robust and very expensive, which may not be an issue if your company is going to pay for it.  You might try a free trial out and see what you think.

Good luck,

-Robert

Answer (score 0):

[Abbot](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml) is one that I'm aware of, which is nice and free. I don't know if that will fit your your situation. You might also look at [UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org/).

Comment: The GUIs I need to test are non-Java based so I don't think either of these tools will help. I've added to my question to make this clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are Java based (commercial) tools for GUI testing like [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/) or [GUIdancer](http://www.guidancer.com/).

If they do not already expose a Java API I am sure that you can talk to their support to add such a feature.

Comment: Squish seems to support non-Java GUIs but not only for cross-platform GUI libraries (Qt, Tk etc.). GUIdancer seems to be only Java Swing. The applications I want to test are MFC-based.

Comment: @Matthew Murdoch Maybe you should add that you want to use MFC to your question (and tags)